# How can I use Promise.all with fs.unlink callbacks?

Tags: node.js, promise

Most modern native or library based functions that require callbacks also return a `Promise` to support promise based workflows.

So I was extremely perturbed when I tried:

```
const rmPromises = []
for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++){
    const fileName = dataPath + i
    rmPromises.push(fs.unlink(fileName))
}
Promise.all(rmPromises).then(() => {
    // carry on ...
})
```

and got the error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`.

Is there a way to work around this and still use `Promise.all` or do I need to implement some workaround? And what would that look like in its cleanest form?

Comment: Hard to see why you would get that particular error message. 
`Promise.all()` accepts Array (of promises), and returns a promise, to which you can chain `.then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - They are getting that error because they are not passing a callback to `fs.unlink()` and the callback is required.

Comment: @jfriend00, OK, understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific error happens because `fs.unlink()` requires that you pass it a callback and you are not.  In addition, it does not return a promise, yet you are trying to use it as if it does.

---

In a current version of node.js (anything that is v10.0 or later), use `fs.promises.unlink` which already returns a promise.

In an older version of node.js, [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) `fs.unlink` like this:

```
const util = require('util');
const unlinkP = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
```

And, then use `unlinkP(yourFile)` instead and it will return a promise.

Comment: Could you please also write down which version of nodejs support fs.promises.unlink in your answer? I think it is more clear.

Comment: @ikhvjs - I added the version to the answer, but the [nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_unlink_path) shows exactly when it was added.